# How does Symfony Security work?

Tags: php, symfony

Please, I need to understand how security works and if it can be overriden.

I've read a lot of Symfony Book and Cookbook, and I'd like to implement my own security access check, can that be done? Because it lacks some functionality in roles, like having a constraint of type `"if is.author then canedit"`

Is it hard to implement? Does FOS UserBundle have this functionality? (Not shown in Docs).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can implement symfony2 Voters to define access right :

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/voters.html

http://kriswallsmith.net/post/15994931191/symfony2-security-voters

Lets create our Voter class :

```
class PostAuthorVoter implements VoterInterface
{
    public function supportsAttribute($attribute)
    {
        return 'POST_AUTHOR' === $attribute;
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return $class instanceof Post;
    }

    public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $object, array $attributes)
    {
        // $attributes is an array so we do a foreach loop
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute)
        {
            // if $attribute is POST_AUTHOR and $object is an instance of Post
            if ($this->supportsAttribute($attribute) && $this->supportsClass($object))
            {
                $user = $token->getUser();

                // assuming that $posts in an \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
                // we check that user's posts contains the current $object
                if ($user->getPosts()->contains($object))
                {
                    return VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED;
                }
                else
                {
                    return VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED;
                }
            }
        }

        return VoterInterface::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
    }
}
```

Then you will be able to call the isGranted method of the security component in your controller like this :

```
if (!$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('POST_AUTHOR', $post)) {
    throw new AccessDeniedException();
}
```